# Find out if an ArrayList contains more than one of an element

Tags: java

I have an array list of usernames and an array list of passwords. Two or more users could have the same password.

```
ArrayList<String> u = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> p = new ArrayList<String>();
```

These arrays are populated from a file of the following format:

```
username  password
```

Like so;

```
String line = null;
String split[] = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
   split = line.split("\\s+");
   u.add(split[0]);
   p.add(split[1]);
}
```

I have a brute force algorithm that generates passwords and I want to find if the passwords generated have a match.

```
String password = bruteForce()
if (passwords.contains(password)){
    int index = passwords.indexOf(password);
    System.out.println("Username: " + usernames.get(index));
    System.out.println("Password: " + password);
}
```

This works well if none of the users have the same password. If two users have the same password; it will just grab the first occurrence and print that, skipping the second user.

I need a way to determine if there are multiple occurrences of the same password, get each occurrences index and then their matching username.

Comment: You should really create a class `User`. You would just have a list of Users and then iterate through it and check each password.

Comment: Initially when I had asked this I was under the assumption that we weren't allowed to implement our own class. After speaking with the professor, I have confirmed that a User class is fine. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Aside from the fact that you shouldn't store plain text passwords or string passwords, to answer the question:

Try using `Collections.frequency`

```
int amount = Collections.frequency(yourCollection, yourObject);
```

As for your design, you could also attempt something a little more bound:

```
List<Tuple<String, String>> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
//Or even making an account object and then
List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
```